# Using custom objects in JDBC insert statement

Tags: esb, mule

I'll copy past a part from the mule website guide:

```
  <jdbc:query key="outboundInsertStatement"
              value="INSERT INTO TEST (ID, TYPE, DATA, ACK) VALUES (#[map-payload:ID], 
                    #[map-payload:TYPE],#[map-payload:DATA], #[map-payload:ACK])"/>
```

I am trying to do something very close to this only I want to use a custom object and not the `java.util.map` which i understand is what is expected.

Could I get an explanation as to what does `#[map-payload:ACK]` exactly means? I dont understand the syntax.

Is `map-payload` some sort of default type?

Could I use that syntax to use a custom object I created? (Some `MesssageObj` class with some fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax:

```
#[evaluator:expression]
```

is used by the [Mule Expression Evaluation framework](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Using+Expressions).

If you look in the [table that lists all evaluators](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Expressions+Configuration+Reference#ExpressionsConfigurationReference-ExpressionEvaluatorReference), you'll find **map-payload** among may other evaluators.

So the example you have above means that:

- it is expected the in-flight message will have a payload of type java.util.Map,
- the values for the ID, TYPE, DATA and ACK columns in the insert query will be extracted from the map payload under eponymous keys.

Of course, feel free to use any other evaluator that better match your in-flight message payload.

Comment: Yea, i've read that but i couldent find what i am looking for.  I was hoping i could find some sort of [#obj:datamember] syntax i could use but i cant seem to make it work.   How can i use these expressions in order to interact with a custom object i created? Say a message object with a title string, body string a datetime obj, i would think there would be something like [#msgInstance:title] and so on. But i dont see that anywhere.   What would be the correct way to do that? The way i do it now is to use a transformer to turn the object into a map, but thats just wasteful and wrong i assume.

Comment: If your custom object is JavaBean-compliant, then use: #[bean:title]. This will call getTitle() on the payload, which is assumed to be your target object. Otherwise, you can use a #[groovy:expression] and get the full capacity of Groovy at your service.